# swing gui application with jni crash?

Tags: java, c++, swing, java-native-interface

hi i develop swing application with try icon that use jni for get shutdown event from windows when i run this app and click on try icon the application crath whith java returend:1
or the log file

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000000000000, 
pid=2928, tid=0x000000000000187c

# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_144-b01) (build 
1.8.0_144-b01)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.144-b01 mixed mode 
windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000000000

# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on 
client versions of Windows



---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000005984e000):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
[_thread_in_Java, id=6268, stack(0x000000005a450000,0x000000005a550000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, ExceptionInformation=0x0000000000000008 
0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000054727960, RBX=0x0000000054727960, RCX=0x00000000ebf6fd00, 
RDX=0x00000000ebf6fd00
RSP=0x000000005a54cec0, RBP=0x000000005a54cfa8, RSI=0x000000005a379568, 
RDI=0x00000000ebc259a0
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x00000000596faeb0, R10=0x000000006b42f240, 
R11=0x0000000002af7b70
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x000000005a54cf50, R14=0x000000005a54cfc0, 
R15=0x000000005984e000
RIP=0x0000000000000000, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000005a54cec0)
0x000000005a54cec0:   000000005984e000 00000000028f80c0
0x000000005a54ced0:   0000000000000000 000000005984e000
0x000000005a54cee0:   00000000ebf6fd00 000000005a37abb4
0x000000005a54cf00:   000000005a379568 0000000000000000
0x000000005a54cf10:   000000005a54cfa8 0000000002913b5e
0x000000005a54cf20:   0000000000000300 00000000000000b6
```

Comment: we can't help without your code, please most a [mcve]. Judging by `pc=0x0000000000000000` you've called a null function pointer

Comment: Crashes like this are usually bugs in the JVM code - so try updating to a more current version of Java where the bug may have been fixed. 1.8.0_181 is the current Java 8.